# Prove if we have a square unitary Matrix $Q$, then $\det(Q) = e^{i\theta}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Prove if we have a square unitary Matrix $Q$, then $\det(Q) = e^{i\theta}$

Using $\det(Q)\det(\bar{Q}^T) = I$, I get to the stage $\det(\bar{Q})\det(Q)=1$, but can't do much else with it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The path is good; now $\det(\bar{Q})=\overline{\det(Q)}$, so...

Comment: ^ but how does $e^{i\theta}$ come out?

Comment: You can conclude that $|\det(Q)|=1$, can't you? How can you write *any* complex number $z$ with $|z|=1$?

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to show that $\det(\bar{A})=\overline{\det(A)}$ for any square matrix. Thus you have

$$
\det(\bar{Q})\det(Q)=\overline{\det(Q)}\det(Q)=1
$$

which means that $|\det(Q)|=1$. Any complex number $z$ with $|z|=1$ can be represented as $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: are you the same egreg from tex community?